# Is it possible to recover from a "last stand" when your rival doesn't kill you?

Tags: max-payne-3

Occasionally when shooting off some heads in multiplayer, I get damaged to the point where it's not enough to kill me but I enter the "last stand" mode -- this is similar to how it is in singleplayer where you have painkillers and an enemy "kills" you but you have a chance to survive if you are able to kill them.

Sometimes just like in singleplayer, when you enter this mode, you don't have a clear shot at your rival (as you fell down behind an obstruction) so you can't recover by killing them. Sometimes my rival is too clueless to know that I'm not dead yet and never moves into my line of sight so I'm stuck there until someone else kills me or I commit suicide.

**Is it possible to recover when in this state without being able to kill my rival eventually?**

I'm just throwing out guesses but I'd imagine I could be revived by a teammate if they can get to me. I have yet to confirm or deny that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not believe you can be revived by a teammate.  However, I think that killing *any* enemy (not just the one who put you in last stand) will revive you.  It's somewhat rare (and always chaotic) that I go into last stand, so I'm not 100% certain of either of those.